# How do I configure checkstyle to flag Javadoc exception @throws comments that shouldn't be there?

Tags: java, checkstyle

During refactoring, a lot of the methods in the app I'm working on have had declared exceptions removed.

Unfortunately while refactoring, the Javadoc was often ignored and the exception Javadoc @throws comment still exists.

How can I get checkstyle to flag this up? I can't see any obvious configuration option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should use the [JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod) check and set its `validateThrows` property to `true`.